# How to timestamp a cell when a range is updated. (multiple times)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have put together this script from multiple answers I found on here, however, I can't figure out how to get it to trigger multiple times on the same active sheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Goals" )
{
var editRange = { // C4:R31
top : 4,
bottom : 31,
left : 3,
right : 18
};

// Exit if we're out of range
var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

// We're in range; timestamp the edit
var ss = e.range.getSheet();
ss.getRange("D2")   // "D" is column 4
.setValue(new Date()); // Set time of edit in "D2"
}}
```

I'd also like it to fire on the following data:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Goals" )
{
var editRange = { // B9:B31
top : 9,
bottom : 31,
left : 2,
right : 2
};

// Exit if we're out of range
var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

// We're in range; timestamp the edit
var ss = e.range.getSheet();
ss.getRange("H2")   // "H" is column 8
.setValue(new Date()); // Set time of edit in "H"
}​}
```

Thanks,
Wyatt

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the returns and move both range checks into the same on edit like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Goals" )
{
var editRange = { // C4:R31
top : 4,
bottom : 31,
left : 3,
right : 18
};

// Exit if we're out of range
var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) ;

var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) ;

// We're in range; timestamp the edit
var ss = e.range.getSheet();
ss.getRange("D2")   // "D" is column 4
.setValue(new Date()); // Set time of edit in "D2"

  var editRange = { // B9:B31
  top : 9,
  bottom : 31,
  left : 2,
  right : 2
  }

// Exit if we're out of range
var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) ;

var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right);

// We're in range; timestamp the edit
var ss = e.range.getSheet();
ss.getRange("H2")   // "H" is column 8
.setValue(new Date()); // Set time of edit in "H"
}}
```